# Bond Nature of a comound

Tags: physical-chemistry, chemical-compounds

How can we determine the type of Bond in LiBaPO4? can we find out the nature of bond through charge transfer values of these elements? if yes then how?

Comment: Chemistry.SE is a better place to ask this questions. But all salts are indeed ionic.